# Select rows from column with same value

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, select

I have a table of book authors, and am trying to get a query result of books by a certain author.

Something like

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE authors = Carl Sagan`

I need all of the columns for each row that matches.

Any help would be appreciated, I'm new to SQL.

Thanks!

Comment: From your description, your query should work. Are you getting errors?

Comment: as you are new to sql, I think your tables will be incorrectly created.
Is relationship created correctly?

Answer (score 3):

Just to clarify, 
Assumptions: 
1.) Carl Sagan authored more than one item in this table.
2.) You want to return all of the occurrences of Carl Sagan.

Original: `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE authors = Carl Sagan`

Should Be: `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE authors = 'Carl Sagan'`

FYI, I use [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/) to test queries. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: HeidiSQL is a **MySQL** tool, the question is tagged with **PostgreSQL**

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I'm new to this website and did not notice the tag.

Answer (score 2):

You have the query correct except that you need to have the text you're comparing to delimited as a string:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE authors='Carl Sagan'
```

Comment: If your answer is solved please remember to select a reply as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems unclear to me, but modify your query by putting a `single quote`

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE authors = 'Carl Sagan'
```